# Magento : Quick View Add to Cart not Showing Product in Minicart Witout Refreshing Page

Tags: magento-1.9, product, addtocart, ajax, mini-cart

I am using custom quick view with ajax. When I add product in cart using this quick view, mini cart show count of product but its not show product there. After refreshing page product show in minicart.

Here is my code used to Ajax add to cart function.

```
     function addtoCart(miniurl){
        var miniurl=miniurl;
        jQuery("#success_message").show();
        jQuery("#success_message").html('<img src="/demo/media/images/loading-round.gif" alt="Loading..." width="77" height="73">');
        var url;
        url = jQuery('#product_addtocart_form').attr('action');

        url = url.replace("checkout/cart", "ajax/index"); // New Code
        if ('https:' == document.location.protocol) {
            url = url.replace('http:', 'https:');
        }
        var data = jQuery('#product_addtocart_form').serialize();
            data += '&isAjax=1';
        try {
            jQuery.ajax({
                url:url,
                dataType:'json',
                type:'post',
                data:data,
                success:function (data) {
                    if(data.status=="SUCCESS"){
                jQuery("#success_message").html(data.message);
                 minicartAjax(miniurl);
                 var qty = jQuery("#qty").val();
                 var curqty = jQuery(".header-minicart .count").html();
                 var newqty=parseInt(qty)+parseInt(curqty);
                 jQuery(".header-minicart .count").html(newqty);
                //jQuery(".header-minicart .label").html('Cart ('+newqty+')');

                    }

                }

            });
        } catch (e) {

        }
    }
    function minicartAjax(url){
    var url = url;
    //alert(url);
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: url,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data){
            var response = data.responseText.evalJSON();
            jQuery(".header-minicart").update(response.minicart);
            //jQuery('#header-cart').html(data.mini_cart);
            alert(response.minicart);
        }
    });
}
```

Custom controller for add to minicart

**app/code/local/Minicart/Quick/controllers/minicartcontroller.php**

```
     <?php
class Minicart_Quick_MinicartController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action{
    public function add_to_minicartAction()
    {
        Mage::log("control get",null,"mini.log");
        $this->loadLayout();
        $layout = Mage::getSingleton('core/layout');
        $block = $layout->getBlock('cart_sidebar');
        $html = $block->toHtml();
        $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode(array('minicart' => $html)));
    }
}
```

**app/code/local/Minicart/Quick/etc/config.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
  <config>
     <modules>
        <Minicart_Quick>
          <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Minicart_Quick>
     </modules>
     <frontend>
       <routers>
          <routeurfrontend>
              <use>standard</use>
              <args>
                 <module>Minicart_Quick</module>
                 <frontName>Quick</frontName>
              </args>
           </routeurfrontend>
       </routers>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

Here is method that I passed custom controller url to addtocart ajax function

```
<?php $miniurl = Mage::getUrl('quick/controllers/add_to_minicart');?>
<button type="button" title="Add to Cart" class="button btn-cart" id="addto-cart" onClick="addtoCart('<?php echo $miniurl;?>')">Add to Cart</button>
```

Comment: You will require to send mini cart html data in Ajax response and then update with javascript code.

Comment: Please find my full code here i try to access the custom controller but its not entering to that function

Answer (score 1):

Rename your file **minicartcontroller.php** to **MinicartController.php** and update content

```
<?php
class Minicart_Quick_MinicartController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action{
    public function add_to_minicartAction()
    {
        $block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('checkout/cart_sidebar')->setTemplate('checkout/cart/minicart/items.phtml');
        $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode(array('minicart' => $block->toHtml())));
    }
}
```

Now update your code

```
<?php $miniurl = Mage::getUrl('quick/controllers/add_to_minicart');?>
```

to

```
<?php $miniurl = Mage::getUrl('Quick/minicart/add_to_minicart');?>
```

Update your minicart function

```
function minicartAjax(url){
    var url = url;
    alert(url);
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: url,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data){
            var response = data.responseText.evalJSON();
            $("YOUR_MINICART_DIV").update(response.minicart);
            alert("hii");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: no change its not entering to the controller file

Comment: Add class `Minicart_Quick_MinicartController` in controller. refer updated controller file code. and Refresh you cache.

Comment: @ Jaimin Sutariya still same issue is there any problem with my modole i mean the config.xml file

Comment: Now i can access the controller but from there i did't get any response in ajax and the product is still not showing in mini cart without refresh

Comment: check updated code for controller and Ajax function.

Comment: @ Jaimin Sutariya still i didnt get any responce in ajax

Comment: in controller  how you return the values in ajax i got internal server error in controller by using this code

Comment: Please update your current controller code to the question.

Comment: updated please check it its the same code you have given

Comment: Check updated controller code.

Comment: now the controller return value but i get in response.minicart value as undefined dont know why its't update the value in minicart please check my ajax function

Answer (score 0):

In addtoCart funtion it seems that you have only update the quantity of mini cart but not update the  content.

You have to update the content alos  in ajax success like

```
jQuery('.top-cart-content').html(data.mini_cart);
```

And in controller where ajax request is sent add below code

```
 if ($this->getLayout()->getBlock('cart_sidebar')) {
                            $sidebarCart = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('cart_sidebar')->toHtml();
                        }
                        if ($this->getLayout()->getBlock('cart_sidebar_mini')) {
                            $mini_cart = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('cart_sidebar_mini')->toHtml();
                        }

$ajaxData['sidebar_cart'] = $sidebarCart;
                        $ajaxData['mini_cart'] = $mini_cart;

$this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($ajaxData));
           return;
```

Comment: i have followed your method while alerting the success data in ajax success function get [object object] after adding it to cart the minicart not appear in the header

Comment: Knowband Plugins i,m getting both minicart and side bar value as null in ajax responce